# Probléme with syntax of closestPoint qwt

Tags: c++, qt, qwt

thank you for helping me use the method of `closestPoint` `qwt` to recover the value of y corresponds to a value x. I put that but still the problem of syntax ?

```
error: invalid type '<unresolved overloaded function types> [int]' for array subscript
```

Code:

```
Curve-> closestPoint (pos [0], NULL);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this error because you call some method, but you use `[]` instead of `()`so you should use:

```
Curve->closestPoint(pos(), NULL);
```

As [doc](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/class_qwt_plot_curve.html#a47620cb8ca3940f7007f8fb990d614f6) said `closestPoint` requires `QPoint`

```
int QwtPlotCurve::closestPoint (const QPoint & pos, double * dist = NULL ) const
```

For example:

```
Curve->closestPoint(QPoint(1,1),NULL);
```